# Unusual Python Pydantic Issue With Validators Running on Optional = None

Tags: python, pydantic

**My py version = Python 3.10.7**

**What is the bug:**
When running test.py (in the attached code below), there will be a validation error on an instance variable that is supposed to be optional.

this is test.py:

```
from myinst import myinst
from pydantic import validate_arguments

from typing import Optional
from pydantic import BaseModel, validator

class myobj(BaseModel):
    somevar: Optional[int] = None
    @validator("somevar")
    def some_validator(cls, var):
        if var is None:
            raise RuntimeError("this error should not show up because validator should not run on None")

@validate_arguments
def somefunc(inst: myobj):
    pass

somefunc(myinst)
```

this is myinst.py:

```
from typing import Optional
from pydantic import BaseModel, validator

class myobj(BaseModel):
    somevar: Optional[int] = None
    @validator("somevar")
    def some_validator(cls, var):
        if var is None:
            raise RuntimeError("this error should not show up because validator should not run on None")

myinst = myobj()
```

**Background info:**
I first found this bug when working on a personal project (code that I will not make public). The project I am working on is thousands of lines of code, and I was able to isolate this bug into these two files. The bug occurs if you run test.py. Interestingly the bug does not occur when the two files are combined or when "myobj" is placed in a standalone module and imported. I am posting this here because I am not entirely sure what the source of the bug is. Any insight is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I am pretty sure this has to do with type coercion. Since those are two _different_ `myobj` classes (which is weird because you defined them exactly the same here), you annotated `somefunc` to take an argument of _one_ type, but you pass an object of a _different_ type (`myinst`) to it. This definitely has nothing to do with `Optional` specifically and nothing with different modules/imports. It has to do with the entire model instance being forcefully validated. I didn't dive deep into this yet, but you can simplify your error example much further.

Comment: Thank you for the response @DaniilFajnberg. In my personal code I am importing the class from a module that is in a parent directory. I saw online that I should add the parent directory to sys.path, but in the other files which import I was not doing this. So I think you are right that python interpreter saw the class as two different classes. After reading your comment I read more about py packages. Now I made my code a package and I am importing using the package notation (with the 'dot' path) everywhere I use the class. I am new to python so I did not know before. Problem solved!